# On retrieving images from json get "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" error

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, data-retrieval

I want to retrieve photos in background using AsyncTask. I get photo as string in base64 encoded form. However, I have "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" error message.

My activity:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ItemClickHandler{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private ArrayList<Device> devices;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(devices, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        initImages();
    }

    private void initImages() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++){
                    final int pos = i;
                    GetImageJSON getImage = new GetImageJSON(MainActivity.this){
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
                            Log.d(TAG, result);

                            if(pos <= recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount()){
                                adapter.updateItem(ImageManager.convertToBitmap(result), pos);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    getImage.execute(ConnectionConfig.getUserItemImage(devices.get(i).getId()));
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

GetImageJSON class:

```html
public class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static String charset = "UTF-8";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
        String result = parseJSONString(args[0]);
        if(!result.isEmpty()){
            try{
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(ConnectionConfig.TAG_RESULT);
                String base64String = jsonObject.getString("image");
                Log.d(TAG, base64String);
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageManager.convertToBitmap(base64String);
                bitmap = ImageManager.scaleDownBitmap(bitmap, context);
                Log.d(TAG, "got result: " + result);
                return ImageManager.convertBitMapToString(bitmap);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static String parseJSONString(String... args){
        String result = "";
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        Log.d(TAG, args[0]);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.connect();

            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception", e);
        } finally {
            try{
                if(inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I could not find any solution. Please, suggest any one. How I can optimize the process of retrieving data.

Comment: where did you initialize `devices` ArrayList ?

Comment: Yes, I get it from previous activity

Comment: did you try with new Runnable() inside the Thread? like `Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
         // code goes here.
    }});  
    t1.start();`

Comment: or just return the Bitmap from `doInBackground`. why toText and toBitmap converting again ?

Comment: I could not change return type of doInBackground

Comment: OK then in `updateItem` use a separate thread and post it back to adapter.

Comment: Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { // code goes here. }}); t1.start(); does not help

Comment: `recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { adapter.updateItem(ImageManager.convertToBitmap(result), pos); Log.d(TAG, "change UI " + pos); adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos); } }, recyclerView.getItemAnimator().getAddDuration());` I added this, but does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure without a runnable version of your code, but I would guess that having the line `ImageManager.convertToBitmap(result)`
in `onPostExecute()` is causing the "too much work on main thread" problem.  Anything that happens in `onPostExecute()` happens on the main thread, so you want to keep that method as light as possible.  As SRB suggested, you could avoid this by having `doInBackground` return the bitmap, instead of a String that needs to be converted back into a bitmap.  Note that to change the return type, you'll need to change `String` to `Bitmap` in two places:

```
public class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO return the bitmap
    }

    //...the rest of your code

}
```

---

On a separate note, it looks like there's some room for improvement in your code.  These are things that aren't directly related to your question but that it'd be good to understand.

1. When you call `getImage.execute()`, `doInBackground` method of the `GetDataJSON` class will be executed.  The `doInBackground` method always runs on  background thread (see "The 4 steps" section [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)), so there's no reason to create a new thread in the `initImages()` method.
2. One of benefits of using a recyclerview is that you don't need to load everything when recyclerview appears on the screen.  If there are views that are off screen, those views can be created when the user scrolls towards them.  By retrieving all the images when the activity is created, you're losing that benefit.
3. There are image loading libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) that will do background image fetches for you.  I don't know what your web API looks like, but if you're able to, using a preexisting library can make it simple to quickly deal with issues like placeholders, caching, resizing, etc.

Comment: I does not help. I changed my code. Full application is in  https://git.4u.uz/Madina-S/MyApplication

Comment: Instead of linking to your entire application, can you create a simple example that reproduces the problem, then post the relevant code bits?  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.